# Is there a way to have Windows active directory give a different ip address?

Tags: active-directory, dhcp

Here is a summary of my problem. I have configured a switch with DHCP capabilities and have connected my machine running Windows Server 2019 to the switch and received an IP from the scope perfectly. No complaints there.
My question is, after having set up my Active Directory with the IP I received from the switch, is it possible to make a DHCP scope that is completely different from the IP received from the switch?

Here is an example to clarify:
My AD server received IP address 192.168.20.19
The switch default gateway is 192.168.20.1

I want to set up DHCP with IP ranges of:
10.10.10.10 to 10.10.10.50
And I want the AD server to have a new IP address within this range. I want this just so I can distinguish the DHCP given IP addesses from the AD-DHCP given IP addresses when I set up other computers with it. Is this even possible?

I appreciate any advice. I am still new to this. This is part of a 1st year course I am taking at college. If someone can guide me in the right direction that would help so much.

Answer (score 0):

There is a lot to unpack here.

- Your DCs should never use dynamic adresses
- You can create as many dhcp scopes as you like, wherever you like
- What is "AD-DHCP"? There is a Windows Server role for that, but besides AD autorization it has nothing to do with AD
- A DHCP (regardless of the vendor) can only offer IP adresses in subnets it has a interface in
- Seperating complete networks by additional gateways ans routes just to "distinguish the ranges" is wayyyy too overthought. You seperate networks logically to *seperate* them (like broadcast domains) from each other.